# Find Last Time a Table was Accessed - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to clean up my SQL Server environment by determining the last time all tables were accessed.  I Googled for a solution and found a few things that seemed like they would work, but I kept getting errors about permissions.

> Msg 300, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>   VIEW SERVER STATE permission was denied on object 'server', database 'master'.
>
> Msg 297, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The user does not have permission to perform this action.

For instance, this link look promising.

http://www.calsql.com/2012/10/sql-server-script-to-know-when-table.html

The thing is, I'm working as a consultant, and as a temp employee, I can't get admin privileges for this DB. Is there any way to list all tables and the last time they were accessed? Again, this environment is somewhat locked down for me.

Comment: No. Permissions exist for a reason and would not do much good if there were a way around them. Go find someone who has permissions and ask them to run it for you.

Comment: If you dont have admin access to the server I doubt very much any of the scripts will work. Short of something really hideous like setting up a trigger on every table to update the timestamp in a seperate table every time a table is hit. Not sexy at all but it could technically work without any special access.

Comment: @ryguy the script in the link you add it it work only if you have admin access . so your problem is that **you dont have admin access.**